# How to get value for IList<model> via form and pass it to controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, razor, ienumerable

I am scratching my head from past two days,including information for what i am trying to build.

Functionality i am trying to build:
simple trip manager application

Get values for trip name and number of people on index page and submit it,which leads to another form(View) where according to number of people textboxes will be generated and pass that form data to another controller where i will be saving it into database.

Models:
**Trip**

```
public class Trip
    {
        public Trip()
        {
            //people = new List<People>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Income { get; set; }
        public decimal Expense { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfPeople { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<People> people{ get; set; }
    }
```

**People**

```
public class People
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TripId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Name:")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Initial Deposite:")]
        public decimal InitialDeposite { get; set; }


    }
```

This is how Index.cshtml View looks like,here i am taking two inputs Name and Number of people:

```
@model TripManager.Models.Trip
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome to Trip Manager";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Trip Manager</h1>
    <p class="lead">Trip Manager helps you calculate your group trip expenses in ease.</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Trip"))
            {

                @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
                @*@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)*@
                <p class="text-info">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)</p>
                <p class="glyphicon-search">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)</p>


                <p class="text-info">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NumberOfPeople)</p>
                <p class="glyphicon-search">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NumberOfPeople) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NumberOfPeople)</p>
                <p><input type = "submit" class="btn-success" name="btnTripInit" value="Go Trip" /></p>
            }
    </div>
</div>
```

Passing these input to member.cshtml View via controller post action Index(Trip trip) which is as below,

```
public ActionResult Index(Trip trip)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(trip);
    }

    var mytrip = new Trip();
    mytrip.Name = trip.Name;
    mytrip.NumberOfPeople = trip.NumberOfPeople;
    mytrip.people = new List<People>(trip.NumberOfPeople);

    return View("Members", trip);
}
```

and members.cshtml view is as below...here i am generating text box for IList in Trip Model....One textbox for name and other for Initial Deposite

```
@model TripManager.Models.Trip
{
   @ViewBag.Title = "Please Enter Members Details";
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      @{
          using (Html.BeginForm("FeedMemberData", "Trip",FormMethod.Post))
          {
            <hr />
            @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
              for(int i=0;i<Model.NumberOfPeople;i++)
              {
                <p>Member @i Details</p>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.people[i].Id)
                <p class="text-info">@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.people[i].Name) @Html.EditorFor(m => m.people[i].Name , new {@class="glyphicon-search"})
                 | @Html.LabelFor(m => m.people[i].InitialDeposite) @Html.EditorFor(m => m.people[i].InitialDeposite , new { @class = "glyphicon-search" })
                </p>
              }
            <hr />
            <p><input type="submit" class="btn-success" name="btnMemberInit" value="Save Details" /></p>
          }
    }
    </div>
</div>
```

Now how should i send this form data to controller and save it to DB via EntityFramework???

```
public ActionResult FeedMemberData(Trip trip)
{
    //TODO
}
```

here for trip i am getting null....

Answer (score 0):

If the Trip object that you expect to be posted to the controller method is null, I find that it is usually caused by an issue with the html page not posting the data correctly or with the MVC model binder that cannot properly resolve the form data into the model, in this case the Trip object) that you expect to be posted to your server.

If I would guess, what you are posting to your method "FeedMemberData" is actually an array of People rather than the Trip object you are using as your model. Try below and see if the model binder will bind the post data to a List.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FeedMemberData(List<People> people)
{
    //TODO
}
```

Comment: No @Jonathan Actually i am posting Trip and my Trip class is having IList<People>.

Comment: @Pratham, sorry I couldn't be more help. Have you tried using a tool such as [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)? Often when I have a controller action that is giving me data that is incorrect or that I did not expect, I can use this free tool to diagnose exactly what is being sent to the server. Also note I have edited my answer to include the [HttpPost] attribute, as I like to be explicit when I am receiving data from a form which controller action I expect to handle the form post.

Comment: thanx for suggestion about fiddler @jonathan. i was able to post right data back to controller

Answer (score 0):

Problem was identified later,Made couple of changes and it worked.

General Note:

If you are facing problem like Ienumerable returning null to Controller,Make sure you are starting indexing from 0 while feeding data to IList

```
@model TripManager.Models.Trip
{
   @ViewBag.Title = "Please Enter Members Details";
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      @{
          using (Html.BeginForm("FeedMemberData", "Trip",FormMethod.Post))
          {
            <hr />
            @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
             //this must start from 0
              for(int i=0;i<Model.NumberOfPeople;i++)
              {
                <p>Member @i Details</p>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.people[i].Id)
                <p class="text-info">@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.people[i].Name) @Html.EditorFor(m => m.people[i].Name , new {@class="glyphicon-search"})
                 | @Html.LabelFor(m => m.people[i].InitialDeposite) @Html.EditorFor(m => m.people[i].InitialDeposite , new { @class = "glyphicon-search" })
                </p>
              }
            <hr />
            <p><input type="submit" class="btn-success" name="btnMemberInit" value="Save Details" /></p>
          }
    }
    </div>
</div>
```